Found a bug in kernel 6.8 (Which Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS is base on). What are my options?
There is a pretty annoying kernel bug https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218881.
It was fixed in kernel 6.9.7.
But my Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS is on 6.8.0-40-generic.
What options do I have?
So far I found:

Upgrade Ubuntu to 24.04 (just released, not sure if stable enough)
Upgrade kernel (from non-official repo only https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/08/install-latest-kernel-new-repository/#google_vignette)
Register a bug-report somewhere for 6.8.0-40-generic and wait for the patch (where ?)
Migrate to another linux distro (out of consideration)
Patch 6.8.0-40-generic by myself (far beyond my skills)

Am I missing something?

The GA kernel stack of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is 5.15, so your first option is using the GA kernel stack (HWE kernel stack for 22.04 is 6.8).  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  If you're interesting in reporting the bug on Ubuntu; refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  (24.04 LTS using HWE will advance (in time) to 6.11 though)

@guiverc I'm not sure downgrading the kernel to 5.15 would be beneficial - couldn't this lead to other issues perhaps?

The 5.15 or GA kernel stack is the most stable kernel option for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, which is why it's the default kernel stack for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server (plus some flavor & other 22.04 media). Other media (including Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop) default to HWE as its often the better option for newer desktop/laptop & graphics hardware.. so which is best or beneficial will depend on requirements and use-case (inc. hardware) of the install.  My 2c @ArturMeinild

I'll try and answer bullet 1-3 (since 4 and 5 are not really relevant).

Ubuntu 24.04 uses the same kernel as 22.04 HWE (currently 6.8). So any bugfix in Ubuntu kernel 6.8 should target both 22.04 and 24.04.

I wouldn't recommend this. If you upgrade to mainline kernel, be aware that you are then running an experimental configuration, that will not necessarily be as stable or get the same security fixes as otherwise.

You could report an Ubuntu bug against the linux package and hope this will get fixed in the 6.8 kernel. However, in this case I'd say it's probably unlikely this bug will get high priority. This is my personal opinion, but this bug is mostly cosmetic, and doesn't have any security implications.


Also see here: How do I report a bug?
Your best bet is actually to wait for the next HWE kernel upgrade (when Ubuntu 24.04.2 is released), which will then have the bug fixed.

Thanks a lot for the great explanation!
I've registered a bun https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-6.8/+bug/2080635 and it's already fixed!
Just need to wait a bit for the new kernel release :)
Cheers!
